# How to show PIN code screen when the app is activated from the background with React native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am developing an app with React native, my problem is to display a PINCode screen when the app is reactivated from the background.
I used `PINCode` component from `@haskkor/react-native-pincode` for the PIN code input screen. It works well when the user login to the app, but I am not sure how to set the configuration or some other statements for displaying this screen when the user reactive the App from the background.
Any answer or comments would be great help to me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)

Just need to manage something in parent component to display pincode component.

AppState will provide you current state of application, and prevState of application can be stored. So your condition can be something like

```
appState = AppState.currentState
AppState.addEventListener("change", websocketManager._handleAppStateChange)

_handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    if (appState?.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active") {
        // Coming from background, so display pincode component.
    } 
    appState = nextAppState
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. would you like to tell me inwhich screen I should put this code? App.js ?

Comment: Yeah I would suggest App.js, as you are going to access that component through out the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement appstate update listener and navigate to any specific screen depending on the state update, details can be found in the following link [Appstate](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)